# Meaning of tel in this context

Tags: grammaire, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

In the example: 'Il y a un expert dans **tel** domaine veut partager sa connaissance avec des gens.'

Why is **tel** used? I thought tel means 'such', so why in the above sentence is '**chaque**' not used instead?

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? It's not grammatically correct.

Comment: From this question [link] (https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27812/comment-sappelle-les-gens-qui-veulent-apprendre-dun-expert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is not a correct sentence. The sentence was probably:

> Il y a un expert dans tel domaine **qui** veut partager sa connaissance avec des gens.

You are not wrong in translating "tel" by "such", as it's indead the case in "tel que", which translate as "such as". But in this context, the correct translation for "tel" is "that" ("such" is ok but not as good IMO).

Your sentence translates to:

> There is an expert in **that** domain who wants to [...]

or

> There is an expert in **such** domain who wants to [...]

---

Here are some tranlations of **tel**:

> Une chose **telle que** celle-ci -> A thing **such as** this one
>   **Tel** père, **tel** fils -> **Like** father, **Like** son
>   **Tel** l'oiseau qui vole, ... -> **Like** the flying bird, ...
>   Je ressentais un **tel** dédain... -> I felt **such** disdain

Comment: Thanks for this, I marked you answer as good. In your examples, why would you say 'Tel père' and not 'Comme père'?

Comment: Also, my example came from this other question https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27812/comment-sappelle-les-gens-qui-veulent-apprendre-dun-expert

Comment: @Cloud For the same reason we don't say "As father, as son". Literally translating, it's fine, but you can see that it's not the good words: "comme" is not usable in a repetition (contrarly to "ni ... ni..." or "tel ... tel...". You can consider it as an expression. You could however say either "Le fils est comme le père" or "Le fils est tel le père".